# Codeigniter ORM unable to ceate relation

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

Trying to establish a simple multiple relation between two tables.

Unfortunately Codeigniter keeps saying:

> "Unable to locate the model you have specified: eventtrigger".

Here comes the code:

```
class Task extends DataMapper
{
    public $has_one = array('employee',
                            'eventtrigger' => array('class' => 'employee'));

    […]
}
```

I know, this is very few information.

But I hope there is a known problem concerning this construct.

regards:*maak*.

Comment: It's exactly what it says it is, Codeigniter can not find the model specified eventtrigger.  Make sure you have created a model titled "Eventtrigger" (with a capital E) and save it in your models folder.

Comment: No that's not what I want. I want to have the employee model as an eventtrigger, because I have multiple relations between these models. The way is described in the docs [here](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/advancedrelations.html) but I can't see my fault

Comment: Hmm... I would say scrap that datamapper thing, it's looks outdated and not actively supported. CI's active record class for working with the DB is very easy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also define the relation's `other_field` property, and you also need to define the reverse relation in the `Employee` model:

```
class Task extends DataMapper
{
    public $has_one = array(
        'owner' => array(
            'class' => 'employee',
            'other_field' => 'owned_task'
        ),
        'trigger' => array(
            'class' => 'employee',
            'other_field' => 'triggered_task'
        )
    );
}
```

And in the Employee model:

```
class Employee extends DataMapper {
    $has_many = array(
        'owned_task' => array(
            'class' => 'task',
            'other_field' => 'owner'
        ),
        'triggered_task' => array(
            'class' => 'post',
            'other_field' => 'trigger'
        )
    );
}
```

For more info on this: http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/advancedrelations.html

Unfortunately, as @bmorenate mentioned, DataMapper isn't actively supported anymore.